# Runtime error while training the model in pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (59) :

```
epochs = 3
print_every = 40
steps = 0

# change to cuda
model.to(device)

for e in range(epochs):
    running_loss = 0
    for ii, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(trainloader):
        steps += 1
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Forward and backward passes
        outputs = model.forward(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()

        if steps % print_every == 0:
            print("Epoch: {}/{}... ".format(e+1, epochs),
                  "Loss: {:.4f}".format(running_loss/print_every))

            running_loss = 0
```

i am getting the below error on above code.

```
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (59) : device-side assert triggered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1524584710464/work/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorCopy.c:20
```

i am using one of the pretrained models from torchvision.models to get the image features. Build and train a new feed-forward classifier using those features.

and i am not sure what i am doing wrong here.
also, i am runing this code on online portal inside jupyter norebook where GPU is enabled.

Thanks in Advance for any help !!